# What does it mean for a stationary distribution to have imaginary values?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, complex-analysis, transition-matrix

Let's say I have a transition matrix P
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.4 & 0.6 & 0. & 0.&  0.\\
 0.5 &0. & 0.5 &0. & 0. \\
 0.6 &0. & 0. & 0.4 &0. \\
 0.7 &0. & 0. & 0. & 0.3\\
 1. &  0.&  0.&  0.&  0. 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The stationary distribution of this matrix, which describes a real-world process, has imaginary values. The Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue is 1. I know for advection processes or processes where stuff stays in the system forever i.e. $\lambda=1$, we deal with imaginary values because those don't disappear. However, I don't know enough about transition matrices to know if the same thing is going on here.

Also, if I wanted to use the stationary distribution as a probability distribution in order to calculate something in expectation, but I end up having imaginary values in the stationary distribution, were I to calculate my expected value as normal, can I still treat it as a proper expectation or is it now meaningless?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that the "stationary distribution has imaginary values"?

Comment: I found the left eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue of P and it had imaginary values in it.

Comment: But the largest eigenvalue of $P$ is $1$, and the left eigenvector of $P$ doesn't (necessarily) have imaginary values in it

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your comment. I only consider the left eigenvector corresponding to the unique largest eigenvalue, which is 1, because I only want to look at the stationary distribution at infinite time. This left eigenvector has imaginary values.

Comment: I don't find that this eigenvector has imaginary values. In particular, I compute the left eigenvector to be
$$
(0.48638132, 0.29182879, 0.1459144, 0.05836576, 0.01750973).
$$
In general, we can always find a real eigenvector associated with a real eigenvalue of a real matrix.

Comment: That is very strange. Could you comment the code that you used to find this eigenvector? I got $$ (0.8259962 +0.j ,       0.3451045 +0.08918493j, 0.3451045 -0.08918493j, 
 0.12813261+0.30355865j, 0.12813261-0.30355865j) $$ using scipy's sparse linear algebra library. I also have just realized that if you compute the eigenvector by hand (assuming eigenvalue is 1) you also have the all ones vector. Anyways, there's something strange going on here and I think it actually doesn't have anything to do with my original question. Mods, feel free to close the question.

Comment: Yes, the right-eigenvector will always be the constant vector because the rows have sum $1$.

Comment: I messed around a bit and I think I found the source of your error: the eigenvectors of the matrix are the **columns** of the second array returned, not the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to compute the eigenvector using the standard scipy linear algebra library:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

mat = [[0.4, 0.6, 0., 0.,  0],
 [0.5, 0.,  0.5, 0., 0.],
 [0.6, 0.,  0.,  0.4, 0.],
 [0.7, 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.3],
 [1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0. ]]
print(la.eig(np.transpose(mat))[1][:,0])
```

The output:

```
[0.8259962 +0.j 0.49559772+0.j 0.24779886+0.j 0.09911954+0.j
 0.02973586+0.j]
```

The eigenvectors of the matrix are the **columns** of the second array returned, not the rows.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the stationary distribution has imaginary values, then there is no stationary distribution. Any Markov chain's state transition matrix will have a complex eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue 1, but not every Markov chain has a stationary distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Actually every Markov chain on a finite state space *does* have a stationary distribution. That's a consequence of the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: I am mistaken, thanks! I learned every finite state-space Markov chain indeed has a stationary distribution. The result which I misrecalled is that the stationary distribution need not be unique if the Markov chain is reducible.